# Radius of circle by knowing a cross section.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have a curve on an ellipse where I know the length of a cross section and need to find out it's radius (vertically and horizontally) and calculate the angle of the curve.

In the following diagram I know $x$ (identical on both sides) and $y$ and need to find $r_1$, $r_2$ and $\alpha$. This seems like a fairly simple problem but i'm stumped..

edit: i also know the length of the arc

[image]

Comment: “Not elementary, Watson!”, because it involves elliptic integrals.

Comment: The question title refers to a circle, but the actual question speaks of an ellipse, that's a bit confusing.

Comment: Wouter: Somebody edited the question. Initially it was about an ellipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from a friend and were able to solve it. Turns out it was a bit easier than i anticipated.

Apologies for an image as an answer (that's what i got), hopefully this still helps somebody else having the same issue:

[image]