# How do I calculate the height of a cross section of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm working on an LED lighting project and have discovered that it involves a little math...

I'm mounting LEDs to plexiglass facing away from the surface I want lighted. I'm looking at cutting a cross section of PVC pipe as a reflector to diffuse the light, so that the light shining through the plexiglass appears smooth and even (ie you can't see bright spots from individual LEDs). I need the reflector to have a very low profile. So now comes the math - what diameter of PVC pipe do I buy in order to obtain the desired cross section?

[image: http://i247.photobucket.com/albums/gg125/puf_the_majic_dragon/circle_zps19f8863c.png]

B, as the base of my cross section, is 2 inches. I'll be playing with different numbers for H, but let's start with 1/2 inch. Is it even possible to determine D (the diameter of the circle)? If so, what would be the equation to do so?

Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670842/radius-of-circle-by-knowing-a-cross-section), but I'm working with a circle, not an ellipse, so mine should be easier. I hope :)

If I start with a circle of D=2, then B=D=2 and H=1. Pretty simple. If I want H to be half, then my (very unpracticed at math) analysis is that D should be double. Am I even on the right track? If so, then if I want H=1/4" I would need a pipe with diameter 8"....

Comment: According to [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius#Radius_from_three_points), you should be able to get the radius of the circle ($ D/2 $) quite easily. Referring to the linked formula, take $ |P_1-P_3| = B = 2 $ and calculate $ \vartheta $ from the fact that $ B/2H = 1/H = \tan(\vartheta/2) $. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not just using the Pythagoras:

$(\frac{B}{2})^2+(\frac{D}{2}-H)^2=(\frac{D}{2})^2$

Thus:

$D=\frac{\frac{B^2}{4}+H^2}{H}$

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out what triangle you were drawing in your head to use Pythagoras. Once I figured it out, it looks like it should work. But I use this formula for H=.5 and I get D=2.5, which seems too small to me. I wish I had a ruler and a compass to play with, but I'm at work right now... Assuming the answer is correct, can you explain why such a small increase in D makes such a big difference for H?

Comment: For a small H you can neglect $H^2$ in the nominator, thus $D$ is indirectly proportional to $H$. Now, if you look at a hyperbola $D=\frac{\text{const}}{H}$, then for a small $H$ it follows: $D$ change very much.

Comment: I totally forgot to mark this as the answer way back when. My apologies for my tardiness.