# Calculate the height of a circle section depending on angles from center

Tags: geometry, circles, spherical-geometry

I need to apply the formula for [the area of the section of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971321/showing-that-the-surface-area-of-a-zone-of-a-sphere-that-lies-between-two-parall). I work with zenith and azimuth angles, and I need to find the height of my sphere section depending on my zenith (theta) angle. I know my sphere radius R, and the two angles that will define the section I'm looking for. I can reason in 2 dimensions for this calculation.

**Given two zenith angles, what is the height of the circle section that emerges?**

Firstly, I need to find the height of the "cap" of my circle, between theta=0 (vertical angle), and theta1.

I'm having trouble putting this in words, so here are two diagrams. I am looking for ***h*** each time:

- for the specific case of the "cap" of the circle:

[image: Trying to solve for h, for theta1 = 0 and theta2 = 45 or whatever.]

- for two different angles, theta1 and theta2:

[image: Trying to solve for h, for theta1 = a value and theta2 = another value.]

Being an outsider to this kind of calculations, I tried to reason with what I already know. I was thinking of finding h using Pythagoras theorem, knowing that h is R - something. But I'm afraid my brain is not wrinkled enough for this! I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774461/how-do-i-calculate-the-height-of-a-cross-section-of-a-circle) that could be a pointer, but OP's question doesn't reason in terms of angles, but of distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using trig in the right-angled triangle, the distance between the cutting plane and the origin is $R \cos \theta$. So in the special case, the height of the cap is $$h = R-R\cos \theta = R(1-\cos \theta)$$ and in the case of the slice you have $$h = R\cos \theta_1-R\cos \theta_2 = R(\cos \theta_1-\cos \theta_2 )$$ assuming that $0\le \theta_1 \le \theta_2 \le \pi$. Note that the special case is simply the normal case with $\theta_1=0$.

Comment: That seems good. Thank you!